# Ensure mutual exclusion in script executed by rule in Alfresco

Tags: javascript, api, concurrency, alfresco

I've got a **rule** (executed in background) set in a **space** which accesses some directories (and checks its existence) to then move some files into them.

I'm basically receiving files with names such as *parentName.documentName.pdf*, where *parentName* is the parent directory name the document should be moved to.

So in the Script below I'm just checking if a "parentName" directory already exists in the current space, crate it if it doesn't, and then move document into it.

Here's the code:

```
var docName = document.properties.name;
var fields = docName.split('.');

var parentName = fields[0];
var fileName= fields[1];
document.properties.name = fileName;
document.save();

var newParentNode = space.childByNamePath(parentName);

//create parent dir if it doesn't exist
if (newParentNode === null) newParentNode = space.createFolder(parentName);

document.move(newParentNode);
```

It will **only** work correctly if I drag files **one after another**. If I drag two (or more) files simultaneously with same *parentName* and there's no *parentName* yet, these two (or more) executions won't find any directory with that name so they all will try to create it. Of course, only first execution will success at creating parent dir, but the rest of them will fail to it since it will already be created.

I'm know basics of Javascript, Alfresco and its JS API, but I'm pretty new to these kind of concurrency problems. Is there any way to ensure mutual exclusion (in Javascript) so I can access those directories safely? I would just need a way to ensure that the second (and following) executions check if parent dir exists once that first is done, so they find out that parent dir already exists and don't try to create it again.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** When a bunch of files enter the space simultaneously, the above error is produced. This means that first execution will create parent node, and move document inside. But the following documents will keep stored at the root of the actual space. Howerver, as a workaround, I can get it to work by **re-running the rule**. It'll move all files to the right parent directory. But of course I'd like it to work at the first attempt so I don't have to re-run the rule manually.

Comment: How do you define nomProjecte variable?

Comment: Wait, that was a mistake copying the actual code. Just translated some variable names to English and forgot to change that one. It's referring to "parentName". I'll edit the question, thanks for pointing out.